# Wanted: PayPal plugin for Wordpress

Tags: plugins, paypal, order

i am currently searching for a wordpress plugin to integrate a paypal purchasing form conveniently to a blog. The goal is to have an order form where users have the option to either decide to order a product home or to purchase the product in digital and receive a tokenized downloadlink - of course after purchase approval from paypal.

does anyone know a plugin for wordpress that does this job?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should check [eShop plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eshop/). It has all the features. Paypal available there

Comment: this plugin looks like it already has too much features :). Do you also know a more minimalistic version to achieve this?

Comment: "Too much features" ... which features *exactly* do you want and which are too many?  eShop provides everything you asked for in your original question.  Anything more minimalistic you'd likely have to write yourself.

Answer (score 0):

WP e-Commerce has tons (too many?) of features, but it's the best for what you're trying to achieve.

[WP e-Commerce](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/)